# Profiling floating point usage in C

Tags: c, floating-point, profiler, primitive

Is there an easy way to count the number of multiplications actually executed by a piece of standard C code? The code I have in mind basically just does additions and multiplications, and it's the multiplications that are of primary interest, but it wouldn't hurt to get counts of the other operations as well.

If it were an option, I suppose I could go around replacing 'a * b' with 'multiply(a, b)' and write a cover function for the native * operator, b/c I really don't care about time performance during this test, but the primary objection to doing *that* is having to re-work a pile of source code just to run the test.

I have no objection to re-compiling the source, perhaps against some library or with obscure (afaik) options. Valgrind came to mind, but if I understand valgrind's purpose, that's more about tracing values than counting operations.

Comment: Look into PAPI? I have used it to count the number of floating point operations in code... worked like a charm. Might be a pain to get configured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your compiler supports soft-float (i.e. using functions with integer implementations to emulate floating-point), you could compiler your program in that mode (`-msoft-float` in GCC), and use your favorite profiling tool to measure how many times they are invoked.

Many processors also have *performance counters* that can count the number of floating-point operations that have been retired.  Depending on the hardware and OS, you may or may not need some amount of kernel support to take advantage of them.

Comment: sweet. apparently you need to link with something to get __muldf3, and there's probably a specific lib to supply it, but I can just squeak my own implementation of __muldf3 into the source.

Comment: @JustJeff: `__muldf3` should be found in `libgcc`, but yes, you can sneak in your own implementation so long as you follow the right ABI (which may be different from your platform's default ABI).

Comment: now if i could just figure out how to make a cover function that just uses the usual * operation, so my _muldf3() could call that. tried compiling one .c file with the fake _muldf3() using -msoft-float, and compiling another .c file with mfoo(a,b) which just returns a*b, without -msoft-float, and then linking the .o files. Now, I can return constants from mfoo(), but not values computed by * , so it seems like I'm missing something. btw, MinGW 4.5.2

Comment: hmm. seems like it's something to do with trying to return floats across the with soft float/without soft float boundary, b/c the junk value I get back seems to depend on what other things happen in the mfoo() routine..

Comment: @justJeff: that would be the ABI mismatch that I spoke of.  If you know some assembly, you should be able to figure out how to return the correct value on your platform.

Answer (score 4):

Compile the source code into assembly language and then search for the multiply instructions.

Note that the optimization level can greatly affect the number that appear.  For loops, you would have to determine the scope of multiplies within a loop and factor that into the result, but if the code is fairly constrained or limited in extent, that should be straightforward.

Comment: Not really what he asked for.  I was about to answer the same, until I realized that such disassembled objects contain no information about which branch paths the running code went down.  In other words, you have no runtime information about the number of multiplies, just information about the number of mul-ish instructions.

Comment: I think this is a good approach, but I question it's scalability and general applicability. For instance, how would you apply this to iterative codes with complex convergence criteria? I understand this is done frequently, but my impression was that it's applicable only to well-understood, small pieces of code... not large, complicated or unknown systems.

Comment: Good direction. What I would do is, compile the code into asm (e.g. using the `-S` option with GCC), add into the resultant asm code a counter variable (32 bits enough?) initialized to 0 and insert a counter incrementing instruction (an at&t syntax equivalent of `add dword [counter], 1`, if x86) before every fmul(p)/fimul instruction (or whatever is doing multiplication on the platform in question). Then recompile the code from asm files, run it in the debugger to see the counter when the program terminates. Of course, the counter and printf() can be added in C prior to generating asm files.

Answer (score 4):

Note: a shameless extrapolation of my comment for as much rep as I can skim.

PAPI has two high-level API functions called PAPI_flips and PAPI_flops which can be used to record the FLOPS as well as the number of floating point operations. Additionally, PAPI offers lots of other performance counter monitoring capability, depending on your processor architecture... cache, bus, memory, branches, etc. I think there is support or support is emerging for graphics accelerators and CUDA/GPGPU.

PAPI will need to be installed on your system, but I think it's widespread enough that installation wouldn't be too painful, if you know what you're doing.

The nice thing about PAPI is that you don't need to know anything about the code; just instrument it (the interface is the same as a stopwatch for FLOPS) and run it. It's based on the actual dynamic execution of your program, so it takes into account things that are hard to account for analytically, such as (pseudo-)random behavior, user/variable input, and related branches.

Comment: To paraphrase Will Rogers: I never meta meta that I didn't like. Enjoy your drive-by.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: Sweet pancakes that's a lot of rep.

Answer (score 1):

The best that I can think of is (assuming you're running gdb):

If you could identify the points were multiplications are occurring, you could then set tracepoints just prior to the multiplication (or perhaps just after them depending on the details), then run the program and count the number of tracepoint dumps.

Yes, it is very crude.  Certainly there are other solutions; however, I would hesitate to trash my stack for something as simple as a count.